# Thumbnails not lined up

Tags: css

Im having trouble lining up the thumbnails (4 blocks). The last block broke to the second line. Is it the width of the container inside div? If I minimize the browser smaller, the blocks are lined up just fine, but no gaps between them. http://magnixsolutions.com/dev/test/test.html.

Also why is the cursor centered in the textfields?

Comment: The <li> elements need less margin-left. But even if you put it down to 17 or so the left or right <li> is cut off a bit. Maybe you'll have to resize the boxes to a lower width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To position the cursor to the left in the textfields, you can use this:

```
.fname, .lname, .zipcode
{
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Your `thumbnails` container is shorter than your `thumbnail` sum their lengths together with their gaps.

Try something like this:

```
.thumbnails {
   margin-left: -15px;
   ...
}

.thumbnails li {
   margin-left: 15px;
   ...
}

.thumbnail {
   width: 220px;
   ...
}
```

This is the modification to your bootstrap css file. So if it does not take any effect, apply !important to enforce them.

UPDATE:

you forgot to apply:

```
.thumbnails > li {
    margin-left: 15px !important
}
```

Comment: I put !important and it still didnt work. See latest http://magnixsolutions.com/dev/test/test.html